# Using Apache on Windows, Access Denied (Code: 5) for folders on network

Tags: wamp, wampserver

My setup is Windows 8 (64), WAMPSERVER 2.5, PHP 5.5.12 (64), and Apache 2.4.9 (64). However I believe this may be relevant for many other WAMP builds.

I needed my PHP application to use a repository of files that are located on a different computer on our network.

I attempted to use code like `scandir('\\\\SERVER-NAME\\dir\\');` but I would get errors like `[function.scandir]: Access is denied. (code: 5)`. Similarly `[function.rename]`, `[function.opendir]`, etc...

Answer (score 10):

The solution was to change the user that service "*wampapache64*" was using.

1. Go to Services (start-key search "View local services")
2. Find service "*wampapache*" or "*wampapache64*"
3. right-click it
4. **Properties**
5. Got to the "**Log In**" tab
6. Click the radio for "This account:"
7. Set the account to "Administrator" or other account with read/write access to the pertinent network folder

Comment: This solution saved me.